# MongoDB executables failed to start (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows, mongodb

Every time I try to run any MongoDB exes on a Windows 10 workstation., I get this error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).

I've tried:

1. installing some VC++ redists
2. reinstalling MongoDB
3. going through the .dll dependencies and copying missing ones into my WOW64 folder.

Now I'm totally at a loss at what to do.

Comment: Have a look https://forum.qt.io/topic/46676/solved-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b/5